# basic php: redirect page using page id

Tags: php

I want to redirect if form update successfully, the page i edit

example:

```
<?php

header("Location: update_lbctn.php?order=2")

?>
```

my problem is in example above `order=2` is dynamic it change depend on page `ID`

so I try like this

```
<?php

header("Location: update_lbctn.php?order=" . echo urlencode($current_id['id']) ." " ")

?>
```

but give me error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
header('Location:update_lbctn.php?order='.urlencode($current_id['id']));
exit;
```

There is no need to add the `echo`. Just concatenate the `id`.

Answer (score 2):

In your Code you have used extra quotes. Just Put the following code. echo is not required while using header redirect as it is, itself a php function

header("Location: update_lbctn.php?order=" .urlencode($current_id['id']))

Answer (score 2):

The header function will echo out the inner content so no need to write echo again.

For this you can write

```
<?php
header("Location: update_lbctn.php?order=".urlencode($current_id['id']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is pass a string to the `Location`.

And with your code, it will redirect to the location specified by the string, not to print it.

So, in your code:

```
<?php
header("Location: update_lbctn.php?order=" . echo urlencode($current_id['id']) ." " ")
?>
```

The echo is unnecessary.

**Why do it is giving syntax error:**

Its because, you are putting `echo` just after the dot `.`.

`echo` is expected to come at the new line where other line ends or at the first line.

In short either after semi-colon `:` or right in the beginning of the file.

e.g.

```
$test = 'gg';
echo $test;
```

or

```
echo $_GET['DUMMY_VAR_FOR_TESTING'];
```

So, its producing syntax error.